# using css or jQuery to prevent a page from responding to events

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

The title is a bit confusing I know but I wasnt quite sure how to word my question.

my site -- http://gx61design.com -- has a alert box that shows up onLoad I need to make it a sort of modal box so that when it shows up you cannot use the arrow keys or hover over the elements in the page like you can at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a global variable to see if user dismissed a dialog and cancel arrow events until a user dismisses the dialog box. So using the code from your page:

```
var can_use_keys = false;

apprise('Hi all, Welcome to may site that was inspired by the original Xbox 360 NXE Dashboard. This site can be navigated by using the Arrow Keys Left and Right', {
    'animate' : true,
    verify : 'true'
}, function(r) {
    if(r) {
        can_use_keys = true;
    }
});
$(".dashboard_panels > div").dashboard({
    point : 'end'
});
$.dashboard.create();

$('body').keydown(function(event) {
    if(can_use_keys === true) {
        if(event.which == '39') {
            $.dashboard.navigate('right');
        }

        if(event.which == '37') {
            $.dashboard.navigate('left');
        }

        if(event.which == '49') {
            $.dashboard.position('init');
        }

        if(event.which == '50') {
            $.dashboard.position('middle');
        }

        if(event.which == '51') {
            $.dashboard.position('end');
        }

        if(event.which == '77') {
            $.dashboard.toggle();
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

or you could put the key binding function in the apprise callback function directly:

```
apprise('Hi all, Welcome to may site that was inspired by the original Xbox 360 NXE Dashboard. This site can be navigated by using the Arrow Keys Left and Right', {
    'animate' : true,
    verify : 'true'
}, function(r) {
    if(r) {
        $('body').keydown(function(event) {

        if(event.which == '39') {
            $.dashboard.navigate('right');
        }

        if(event.which == '37') {
            $.dashboard.navigate('left');
        }

        if(event.which == '49') {
            $.dashboard.position('init');
        }

        if(event.which == '50') {
            $.dashboard.position('middle');
        }

        if(event.which == '51') {
            $.dashboard.position('end');
        }

        if(event.which == '77') {
            $.dashboard.toggle();
        }

});
    }
});
$(".dashboard_panels > div").dashboard({
    point : 'end'
});
$.dashboard.create();
```

Answer (score 2):

We use jQuery UI - Dialogs in our present project. The [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message) throws up a mask that will prevent interaction with the page underneath until the user clicks a button or dismisses the dialog window.

Very easy to use!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to put a (semi)-transparent `div` over your page with the modal dialog on top. The [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples) plugin is the simplest script I know of that does this for you.

Anyways, these are called "modal dialogs" and googling will turn up endless resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with JQuery. Use jquery model dialog and set the `model` option to `true`.

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <p>your message here...</p>
</div>

   <script>
    $(function() {

        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            modal: true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal